# Problem with Swift Extensions and NumberFormatters

Tags: ios, swift, numbers, formatter

I'm trying to format the text field of a label such that its text will only print values with a certain number of significant digits. I'm using the extension functionality of Swift  and the *NumberFormatter* class but, while the code complies correctly with no errors, the functionality I want (i.e. a maximum of 6 significant digits) is not being implemented.

Here's my extension code:

```
extension Double {
    func formatNumbers() -> String {
        let numberFormat = NumberFormatter()
        let number = NSNumber(value: self)
        numberFormat.usesSignificantDigits = true
        numberFormat.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        return String(numberFormat.string(from: number) ?? "")
    }

}
```

And here's when I call the extension method:

```
ConsoleValue.text! = "\(tempResult.formatNumbers())"
```

where *ConsoleValue* is a *UILabel* and *tempResult* is a *Double var*.

Can someone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using string interpolation? `tempResult.formatNumbers()` is already a string

Answer (score 0):

To set the maximum number of significant digits, use the [`maximumSignificantDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1412008-maximumsignificantdigits) property :

```
numberFormat.maximumSignificantDigits = 6
```

---

According to this wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures), significant figures are :

> - All non-zero digits are significant: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.
> - Zeros between non-zero digits are significant: 102, 2005, 50009.
> - Leading zeros are never significant: 0.02, 001.887, 0.000515.
> - In a number with a decimal point, trailing zeros (those to the right of the last non-zero digit) are significant: 2.02000, 5.400, 57.5400.
> - In a number without a decimal point, trailing zeros may or may not be significant. More information through additional graphical symbols
>     or explicit information on errors is needed to clarify the
>     significance of trailing zeros.

Comment: It still doesn't work, I tried with that too. According to Apple documentation, the fault number is 6, hence why I did not specify it.

Comment: It does not format the number, i.e. the string can still have more than 6 significant digits when the number goes that high

Comment: @PepeCarval Give me an example of a number that you are feeding to this function

Comment: I'm using it in a calculator app, and basically multiplying 10*10 and that result by 10, and so on.